# How do I set Lose It! to use the metric system?

Tags: lose-it

How can I set up Lose It! to display and record using the metric system?

[Lose It!](http://loseit.com) is a service to help you lose weight and I really like it but I'm not used to measuring things in imperial units such as pounds and feet, etc.

Is there a way to change the settings to metric?

Comment: Try one of [these](http://www.xmarks.com/site/www.loseit.com/).

Comment: Slight change in your question to be more about getting the most out of it and less of a list/recommendation question

Answer (score 2):

Click the "Settings" gear.

[image: "Settings" gear, highlighted]

Choose "Unit Preferences".

[image: "Unit Preferences" highlighted]

Choose the units you want for each type of measurement.

[image: screen shot of unit preferences page]